# delete data information

Tags: sql-server-2005

One of my colleague deleted records from a tables 15 days before. I could not know who are deleted those records. I want know their information on which machine, username and modified date in sqlserver2005. How can i get these information? please suggest?

Thanks,
Mailam

Comment: "he's been a very naughty boy!" - in best python-esque voice

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* unless you have the appropiate columns and/or history tables and/or features like [CDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627397.aspx) enabled.

By default, there is no in-built automatic mechanism to record data changes